# Quickly find definition in header

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, header-files

I am using Eclipse CDT for my C Development on my linux machine.

Is there any function in the Eclipse IDE witch allows you do quickly find undefined symbols in header files that are not included?

I have this simple function call :

```
close(STDIN_FILENO);
```

**STDIN_FILENO** is not defined I don't know where to search for it, now I am using google to find the function headers but is there any fast way ?

Comment: Don't you have a `jump to definition` button?

Comment: This is probably an overkill, but as a last resort you can go to the root directory of your source tree and do: `find -type f | grep "\.\(h\|c\)$" | xargs grep "#define STDIN_FILENO"`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F3</kbd> is the way to go, but going a bit further, you might also want to take a look at ctrl+shift+t to browse all the tokens available and ctrl+shift+r to browse all the files.